# There are some issues on scrolling, checkbox, and slider after migrating from UIWebView to WKWebView

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm currently migrating from UIWebView to WKWebView. After migrating, I realised that scrolling, checkbox and slider (to be specific, I'm using rzSlider) having issues.

The height of the scroll view seems ran out of margin while checkbox became inconsistent and slider not able to slide.

I'm developing a hybrid app using Ionic version 1.2.4 and iOS 9.2.